# Convert fit(X, Y, 'smoothingspline') from Matlab to C or Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, c, matlab, spline, smoothing

I can't run Matlab coder on this function

```matlab
function FT = fitsmooth(X, Y)

FT = fit(X, Y, 'smoothingspline');
```

because I get this error:

> ??? The function 'fit' is not supported for standalone code generation. See the documentation for coder.extrinsic to learn how you can use this function in simulation.

I need this functionality in an iOS app I'm building that incorporates an algorithm already written in Matlab.

Any idea how I can convert `fit(X, Y, 'smoothingspline')` to C or Objective-C, where X and Y are one-dimensional arrays of the same length?

Comment: You can't, it's not supported, see http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/coder/ug/functions-supported-for-code-generation--alphabetical-list.html

Comment: That's the point of this question. I'm looking for a C or Objective-C alternative to Matlab's `fit` function for the case where `fitType` is `'smoothingspline'`.

Comment: This question may gather more attention if the title reflected that you are looking for an interpolation library in C or Objective-C that supports smoothing splines. If such a library is found, it can be called from your MATLAB code for code generation using `coder.ceval`.

Comment: I have been asked to replicate exactly the results of the Matlab code I have been supplied. Nothing less. Either it is possible or not.